# Django-taggit how to modify to have same tag added by different user

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-taggit

I am trying to modify `django-taggit` to allow the same tag to be added by separate teams.

I have modified `django-taggit` Model so that it has `user` and `team_id` values added when a user adds a new tag to `taggig_tag` table. This also adds  `user` and `team_id` values to `taggit_taggeditems` table.

The goal is to allow teams to edit or delete their own tags and that should not affect other teams, so different teams need to have their own separate sets of tags.

In my modified scenario, the tag `name` and `team_id` constitute a distinct tag. I expect i can test `team_id` or concatenate it to the tag `name` before `django-taggit` tests for distinct tags. But do not see where `django-taggit`  does that.

Question: Where in the `django-taggit` code does it look for duplicate tag values?

```
`apps.py`
`forms.py`
`managers.py`
`models.py`
`utils.py`
`views.py`
```

My modified `django-taggit` Model code is below.

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.db import IntegrityError, models, router, transaction
from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.utils.translation import gettext, gettext_lazy as _
from django.conf import settings
### MODIFICATION: added django CRUM to get request user
from crum import get_current_user


try:
    from unidecode import unidecode
except ImportError:

    def unidecode(tag):
        return tag


class TagBase(models.Model):
    ### MODIFICATION: added team and user to model, removed unique=True
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("Name"), max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name=_("Slug"), max_length=100)
    team_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False, null=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, 
       on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.name.lower() > other.name.lower()

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.name.lower() < other.name.lower()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ### MODIFICATION: added team and user to taggit_taggeditem model
        ### get request user with django CRUM get_current_user()
        self.user = get_current_user()
        self.team_id = get_current_user().team_id

        if self._state.adding and not self.slug:
            self.slug = self.slugify(self.name)
            using = kwargs.get("using") or router.db_for_write(
                type(self), instance=self
            )
            # Make sure we write to the same db for all attempted writes,
            # with a multi-master setup, theoretically we could try to
            # write and rollback on different DBs
            kwargs["using"] = using
            # Be oportunistic and try to save the tag, this should work for
            # most cases ;)
            ### MODIFICATION: remove IntegrityError try/except for unique 
               which is removed
            #try:
            with transaction.atomic(using=using):
                res = super().save(*args, **kwargs)
            return res
            #except IntegrityError: 
            #    pass
            ### MODIFICATION: remove slugs create as no longer checking for 
               duplicate slugs
            # Now try to find existing slugs with similar names
            #slugs = set(
            #    self.__class__._default_manager.filter(
            #        slug__startswith=self.slug
            #    ).values_list("slug", flat=True)
            #)
            i = 1
            #while True:
            #    slug = self.slugify(self.name, i)
            #    if slug not in slugs:
            #       self.slug = slug
            #        # We purposely ignore concurrecny issues here for now.
            #       # (That is, till we found a nice solution...)
            #        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
            #    i += 1
            while True:
                slug = self.slugify(self.name, i)
                #if slug not in slugs:
                self.slug = slug
                # We purposely ignore concurrecny issues here for now.
                # (That is, till we found a nice solution...)
                return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
                i += 1
        else:
            return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def slugify(self, tag, i=None):
        slug = slugify(unidecode(tag))
        if i is not None:
            slug += "_%d" % i
        return slug


class Tag(TagBase):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Tag")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Tags")
        app_label = "taggit"


class ItemBase(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return gettext("%(object)s tagged with %(tag)s") % {
            "object": self.content_object,
            "tag": self.tag,
        }

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    @classmethod
    def tag_model(cls):
        field = cls._meta.get_field("tag")
        return field.remote_field.model

    @classmethod
    def tag_relname(cls):
        field = cls._meta.get_field("tag")
        return field.remote_field.related_name

    @classmethod
    def lookup_kwargs(cls, instance):
        return {"content_object": instance}


class TaggedItemBase(ItemBase):
    tag = models.ForeignKey(
        Tag, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_items", 
           on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    @classmethod
    def tags_for(cls, model, instance=None, **extra_filters):
        kwargs = extra_filters or {}
        if instance is not None:
            kwargs.update({"%s__content_object" % cls.tag_relname(): 
               instance})
            return cls.tag_model().objects.filter(**kwargs)
        kwargs.update({"%s__content_object__isnull" % cls.tag_relname(): 
           False})
        return cls.tag_model().objects.filter(**kwargs).distinct()


class CommonGenericTaggedItemBase(ItemBase):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name=_("Content type"),
        related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_tagged_items",
    )
    content_object = GenericForeignKey()
    ### MODIFICATION: added team and user to taggit_taggeditem model
    team_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False, null=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, 
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    @classmethod
    def lookup_kwargs(cls, instance):
        return {
            "object_id": instance.pk,
            "content_type": ContentType.objects.get_for_model(instance),
            ### MODIFICATION: added team and user to taggit_taggeditem model
            "user": get_current_user(),
            "team_id": get_current_user().team_id,
        }

    @classmethod
    def tags_for(cls, model, instance=None, **extra_filters):
        tag_relname = cls.tag_relname()
        kwargs = {
            "%s__content_type__app_label" % tag_relname: 
                model._meta.app_label,
            "%s__content_type__model" % tag_relname: model._meta.model_name,
        }
        if instance is not None:
            kwargs["%s__object_id" % tag_relname] = instance.pk
        if extra_filters:
            kwargs.update(extra_filters)
        return cls.tag_model().objects.filter(**kwargs).distinct()


class GenericTaggedItemBase(CommonGenericTaggedItemBase):
    object_id = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_("Object id"), 
        db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class GenericUUIDTaggedItemBase(CommonGenericTaggedItemBase):
    object_id = models.UUIDField(verbose_name=_("Object id"), db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class TaggedItem(GenericTaggedItemBase, TaggedItemBase):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Tagged Item")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Tagged Items")
        app_label = "taggit"
        ### MODIFICATION: added team_id and user to taggit_taggeditems table 
           constraints
        index_together = [["content_type", "object_id", "team_id", "user"]]
        unique_together = [["content_type", "object_id", "tag", "team_id", 
           "user"]]
```

Comment: The name field for the Tag class has been defined as unique, I'm not sure what you are asking is possible using that library out of the box. You could possibly fork the project to remove the constraint but I imagine it wouldn't be the only thing you have to change

Comment: https://github.com/jazzband/django-taggit/blob/master/taggit/models.py#L16

Comment: So far have done following in `django-taggit` model: 1) remove Tag class `name` field `unique=True` 2) add `team_id` to `TaggedItem` class `index_together` and `unique_together` constraints, 3) disabled `if slug not in slugs` check for existing slugs before save. But clearly more to do. Can anyone who has worked with `django-taggit` before give me an idea if this requires many changes in all files, or few specific changes in one or two files?

Comment: I abandoned trying to modify taggit for above purposes and have just created many to many tag relationship to a single object (in my case photos) using `inlineformset_factory` to add and delete tags. Not as pretty or simple for end user as taggit but allows `team_id` to be added to  the photo / tag relationship.